# Can't join any servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I recently purchased Minecraft, and when I try to join servers they say `Invalid Session` and tell me to restart the game. I have made a Minecraft account and logged in but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the game?

Answer (score -1):

Restart you game, including the launcher, if that fails, restart the computer.